# Java Generics: Lower and Upper Bound wildcards usecase for different formal type parameter

Tags: java, generics

See code snippet below

```
List<? extends Exception> list1 = new ArrayList<IOException>();
List<? super IOException> list2 = new ArrayList<Exception>();
```

Is there any real usecase to have `new ArrayList<IOException>()` and `new ArrayList<Exception>()` on the right side and how this could be helpful?

Comment: You can certainly just use the diamond syntax on the RHS.

Comment: @DavidConrad, I agree. But is there any sense to ever use "new ArrayList<IOException>()" or "new ArrayList<Exception>()" instead of diamond operator?

Comment: There's no difference. You can only write `null` to `list1` and read `Object` from `list2`.

Comment: I can't see any reason to.